# return false;event.preventDefault not work for 1password auto-submit

Tags: javascript, forms, submit

My website has only an ajax submit way for login,so when the form submited directly ,it will return a json data and refresh the page.so I want observe the submit event and trun it to the ajax way,but I can not prevent the auto-submit,I tried many ways to prevent the 1password auto-submit from submit ,but failed,so I try to get some help here,thanks a lot!

**javascript**

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

**1password extension auto-submit Code**

```
var a = document.forms[0];
var b = document.createEvent('UIEvent');
b.initEvent('submit', !0, !0, window, 1);
a.dispatchEvent(b);
a.submit();
return !0;
```

**The environment**

Mac pro both in chrome,safari,firefox

**question**

- the extension initEvent allow the event.preventDeafault function,but why it is not work?
- why the initEvent function in the extension has 5 arguments not 3
- how to stop the auto-submit by 1password extension

This is my first question here, if I have made any mistakes, please tell me! I will be very grateful for any help!

**add solution**

- when the onsubmit is called ,use a setTimeout to stop the submit action.chrome and firefox works well,but in safari,this method will stuck the page

  ```
  setTimeout(function() {
      try {
          document.execCommand('Stop');
      } catch (_error) {
          e = _error;
      }
      try {
          return window.stop();
      } catch (_error) {
          e = _error;
      }
    }, 0);
  ```
- the 1password extension will try to click the submit button,so I just remove the form action attribute and listen to click event of the submit button,and it works well,thanks a lot for Arun P Johny's help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check whether default was prevented before calling submit by using [event.defaultPrevented](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/defaultPrevented)

```
var a = document.forms[0];
var b = document.createEvent('UIEvent');
b.initEvent('submit', !0, !0, window, 1);
a.dispatchEvent(b);
if (!b.defaultPrevented) {
    a.submit();
}
return !0;
```

In your case, you are dispatching an event, but that has nothing to do with the actual submit call, also calling the submit programatically will not trigger the submit event. so what you can do is to check whether the default action was prevent by checking the `defaultPrevented` attribute as shown above.

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gas400n6/)

Comment: it works in chrome console,auto-sbumit is prevented,but the code is in the 1password extension,I can not change everyone's plugin

Comment: thanks a lot Johhy,I understand now,in fact,the question is just how to stop the form.submit( ),the dispatchEvent is just tell me there is a submit